# get_user_pages failed for PCIe memory

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have mapped the pci memory in user space like

```
fs = open("/dev/mem",O_RDWR | O_SYNC);

mmap_src = mmap(NULL, BUFF_COUNT, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fs, 0xe0000000);
```

`0xe0000000` is the addressof pci memory device.

After mmaped get succeeded, I pass that address to driver using ioctl function.

In driver code,

I call `get_user_pages` from that address which i got from ioctl.

In execution, `get_user_pages` call fails.

Any idea to how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

get_user_pages return the struct page pointer for the valid physical memory and not for IO memory, so it is expected that get_user_pages will fail for PCI memory. Untill and unless you give more details about your design its hard to suggest how to fix it.